# Way to print entirety of error message cut off in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, jax

The error is with the Jax `scan` function, and gives this message:

```
TypeError: scan carry output and input must have same type structure, got PyTreeDef((CustomNode(<class 'brax.experimental.braxlines.training.env.EnvState'>[()], [CustomNode(<class 'brax.envs.env.State'>[()], [CustomNode(<class 'brax.physics.base.QP'>[()], [*, *, *, *]), *, *, *, {'agent_idx': *, 'reward': *, 'reward_contact_cost': *, 'reward_ctrl_cost': *, 'reward_forward': *, 'reward_survive': *, 'score': *}, {'agent_idx': *, 'first_obs': *, 'first_qp': CustomNode(<class 'brax.physics.base.QP'>[()], [*, *, *, *]), 'rng': *, 'static_agent_policy': {'normalizer': (*, *, *), 'policy': [{'params': {'hidden_0': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_1': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_2': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_3': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_4': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}}}, {'params': {'hidden_0': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_1': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_2': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_3': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_4': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}}}]}, 'steps': *, 'truncation': *}]), {'agent_idx': *, 'reward': *, 'reward_contact_cost': *, 'reward_ctrl_cost': *, 'reward_forward': *, 'reward_survive': *, 'score': *}, *]), [CustomNode(<class 'flax.core.frozen_dict.FrozenDict'>[()], [{'params': {'hidden_0': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_1': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_2': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_3': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}, 'hidden_4': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}}}])], (*, *, *), [None], *)) and PyTreeDe...
```

Verbatim, with the ellipsis at the end. I want the full, non-truncated message. Is it possible to print it to a txt file or force Colab to print it or something?

You can reproduce a similar error message with the following:

```
def f(carry, xslice):
  new_carry = carry['this'] * 2
  return new_carry, xslice

jax.lax.scan(f, init={'this': 1}, xs=(), length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround here would be to simply encapsulate the call in a `try-except` block like this:

```py
try:
    jax.lax.scan(f, init={'this': 1}, xs=(), length=2)
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
```

This will catch and print the exception as pure string.